# How to troubleshoot ethernet port on laptop

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a problem with my wired connection. 
To be more specific, my laptop doesn't seems to recognize that I have plugged in an ethernet cable.

I tried to download new drivers for my ethernet card, but I couldn't find any solutions. Maybe because I am new to Linux, so I'm not familiar with running commands in the terminal.

OK I have typed the command and here are the results:

```
00:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [1039:0191] (rev 02)
```

For the second reply I don't know if the following is what you asked me:
⠀Memory: 3.9 GiB
⠀Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P8800 @ 2.66GHz × 2
⠀OS type: 32-bit

My Ethernet connection had some problem on Windows too. 
I have changed recently my internet provider, and since then my ethernet cable is not recognized by the laptop. At that time I was still on Windows. I thought that with Ubuntu the problem would be solved, but unfortunately the problem still persists. If someone can help me to solve my problem I'll be thankful.

Here are the results of the three first commands you told me to run:

```
lsmod | grep sis190 
sis190                 22570  0

sudo modprobe sis190

ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:90:81:7e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22672 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:22672 (22.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:d3:2c:3a:ae  
          inet addr:192.168.1.72  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:d3ff:fe2c:3aae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:71992 (71.9 KB)  TX bytes:52000 (52.0 KB)
```

and the results of running the last two commands:

```
dmesg | grep -e eth -e sis190 
[    0.816667] sis190: sis190 Gigabit Ethernet driver 1.4 loaded 
[    0.816728] sis190 0000:00:04.0: setting latency timer to 64 
[    0.816751] sis190: 0000:00:04.0: Read MAC address from EEPROM 
[    0.904032] sis190: 0000:00:04.0: Realtek PHY RTL8201 transceiver at address      
[    1.416030] sis190: 0000:00:04.0: Using transceiver at address 1 as default 
[    1.448235] sis190 0000:00:04.0: eth0: 0000:00:04.0: SiS 191 PCI Gigabit Ethernet adapter at f8410000 (IRQ: 19), 00:90:f5:90:81:7e 
[    1.448238] sis190 0000:00:04.0: eth0: GMII mode. 
[    1.448243] sis190 0000:00:04.0: eth0: Enabling Auto-negotiation 
[   11.560907] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.372019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.372265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   26.424038] sis190 0000:00:04.0: eth0: auto-negotiating...

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------   Type:              Wired   Driver:            sis190   State:         
unavailable   Default:           no   HW Address:       
00:90:F5:90:81:7E

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: Please open a terminal. Enter this code and press Enter: lspci -nn | grep 0200. The pipe symbol | is on the right-side of my US keyboard on the same key with \. The terminal will report back details about your ethernet card. Edit your question to add those details and we'll proceed.

Comment: What hardware (laptop model) are you on? Does it work when booted in Windows?

Comment: I am ready to proceed @chili555 if you can help me trouble-shoot my problem thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few months ago with one of my laptops (a Dell Inspiron E1505, though I don't think that the answer below is dependent on your laptop being the same model). I realize that there are multiple causes for an ethernet jack not recognizing that a cable is connected to it. Having said that, this might be worth trying the steps below before you do a lot of troubleshooting.

This answer comes from http://vittalp88.blogspot.com/2011/03/network-cable-unplugged-but-it-isnt.html. I'm hoping I don't get down-voted just because it sounds so ridiculous. With my own laptop, I only tried it after several hours of troubleshooting. However, this solution worked (though I'm not sure why; neither is the author of the linked post, apparently):

1) Turn your laptop off.
2) Unplug the battery.
3) Leave it (with battery unplugged) for an hour.
4) Put the battery back in, boot up, and see if the ethernet jack is working again.

Perhaps it's worth trying this before doing much else?

(Note: The link above talks about having this problem in Windows. When I used the solution, it fixed the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: OK I have tried this but with no success ... thank you for the reply but it seems more complicated unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your ethernet device uses the driver sis190. Is it loaded?

```
lsmod | grep sis190
```

If not, load it manually:

```
sudo modprobe sis190
```

Does your ethernet come to life?

```
ifconfig
```

If so, let's get it to load automatically on boot:

```
sudo su
echo sis190 >> /etc/modules
exit
```

If your ethernet doesn't connect as expected, look for error messages:

```
dmesg | grep -e eth -e sis190
```

See if the system recognizes that a cable is attached:

```
nm-tool
```

Comment: when I do the command lsmod | grep sis190 the terminal gives me this  sis190                 22570  0       Is this mean that it's loaded?

Comment: Exactly. So go on to the other questions: dmesg | grep -e eth -e sis190 and nm-tool.

Comment: OK I have edited my question with the data you asked me ...

Comment: 'carrier: off' suggests the cable or the port at the router are defective. Can you try another cable and another port at the router? On the other hand, 'autonegotiating' suggests it's at least trying. I see nothing remarkable that needs fixing with the driver.

Comment: OK I tried both of your suggestions. There is apparently no problem with the cable or the port of the modem because I have a notebook (which have Ubuntu 12.04 installed too) that connects perfectly. So what are you suggesting if there is something to suggest.... ( thanks for your time ).

Comment: Network Manager is designed to connect one interface at a time. You have a wireless connection. Please Edit Connections in Network Manager, select Wireless and uncheck Connect Automatically.' Reboot and see if your wired ethernet connects.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing append ... it seems that there is a problem with DHCP settings or with the IP address it's like it can't get an IP address for the wired connection...

Comment: What settings have you added in Network Manager? Typically, you needn't any. If there are any, remove them. I have never met a sis190 that I didn't have trouble with.

Comment: I just unchecked the connect automatically for the wireless connection like you said . all the other settings are by default so i didnt add anything...

Comment: Except for replacing the card, I am reluctantly out of suggestions.

Comment: ok I see it's hopeless ... thank you for the help anyway.